# How cfs s3 uploading works

Tags: meteor, amazon-s3

I've previously used `slingshot` and the process it pretty simple: we upload the image and it returns the uploaded url of the s3 bucket.

Now I want to resize the image and need to perform some operations on the image, so I switched to the `cfs:s3` package. But when I try to upload the image, it returns some record with no url and in the db it stores it as:

```
{
    "_id" : "Rwa7Xo65pv6cAP2aY",
    "copies" : {
        "thumbs" : {
            "name" : "306032-facebook.jpg",
            "type" : "image/jpeg",
            "size" : 4262,
            "key" : "thumbs/Rwa7Xo65pv6cAP2aY-306032-facebook.jpg",
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-02-14T06:44:04.476Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-02-14T06:44:04.476Z")
        }
    },
    "original" : {
        "name" : "306032-facebook.jpg",
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-01-30T09:48:58.000Z"),
        "size" : 4262,
        "type" : "image/jpeg"
    },
    "uploadedAt" : ISODate("2015-02-14T06:43:59.062Z")
}
```

- How can I get the URL from this record? (I suppose it is `key` in thumbs) Is it linking my server url to amazon s3 url?
- What are the advantages of this method over `slingshot`?
- How do I know the upload is completed? I can't figure out any ui helpers, are there any reactive helpers to track download percentage?

Answer (score 0):

1. The URL will be your s3 end point (e.g. s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/) + the key. I suggest you to create a constant for your end point and a register helper to return the URL.

Something like this

```
Template.registerHelper('THUMBS_URL', function(key){
  return S3_ENDPOINT + key;
})
```

2. I haven't used slingshot yet so can't comment on it.
3. There is a isUploaded helper function in collectionFS.

https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#isuploaded